# NodeJS Google API: create and write to sheet

Tags: node.js, google-api, spreadsheet

I want to create a new file and write the data there.

```
return sheets.spreadsheets.create(createOption).then(response => {
        return sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(
          {
              spreadsheetId: response.data.spreadsheetId,
              range: 'A:A',
              valueInputOption: 'RAW',
              resource: resource,
          }).then(result => {
            return {isOk: true, data: result}
        }).catch(error => {
            return {isOk: false, error}
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        return {isOk: false, error}
    })
```

This code used to work, but now it doesn't give an error or a result. And I can't understand what happened.

try {} catch also does not catch errors. are there any other ways to figure out what's wrong?

```
const createOption = {
        resource: {
            properties: {
                title: 'Subscribe #' + sub_id
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Although unfortunately, I cannot confirm your variables of `createOption` and `resource` in your script, when I test your script using sample values, I cannot replicate your situation, and no error occurs and a new Spreadsheet is created and the value is put to the 1st tab of the created Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detailed information for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, are you using the latest version of googleapis for Node.js?

Comment: yes, latest version, 100

Comment: I added an example of the parameters to the description

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize again. Unfortunately, when I tested your script, again, no error occurs and a new Spreadsheet is created and the value is put to the 1st tab of the created Spreadsheet. So, I cannot still replicate your situation. But, when I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to try to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I think that I have to study more.